# ActiveAdmin record activation page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, activeadmin

I'm working on an application for which the admin has to activate 'topics' before they are shown. The topics table simply has a column called `active`.

I'm using the ActiveAdmin gem for the rest of the admin panel and I also have an edit page for topics where every aspect of the topic can be changed. However, I would also like to have a secondary page for topics which would only display that title, and make it possible to activate the topic (without being able to change the other columns). I'm sure this would be more user-friendly, but I don't know how to go about it, or if it is even possible.

I have the impression that only one edit page can be made for each model.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

topic.erb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :pending, where(:active => false)

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :solutions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :solutions, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => Proc.new{|attributes| attributes["title"].blank?}

  acts_as_taggable

end
```

Comment: Do you want a new register for Topics on ActiveAdmin or a view under the topics resources?

Comment: I'd prefer a new register, but an extra view would work too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try it right now myself, but I'd say you want something like this as ActiveAdmin configuration:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Topic do
  scope :pending

  menu :label => 'Activate Topics'

  # if you want it as submenu of 'Topic':
  # menu :parent => 'Topic'

  index do
    column :active
  end
end
```

Where the `pending` scope would be a model scope for just showing the pending (not active) topics. Like:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :pending, where(:active => false)

  # ...
end
```

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: This seems to work and right now I have two files for Topic: topic.rb and topicactivation.rb. Problem is that both link to the topicactivation page in the banner. Any idea how to make them ork as separate files? And for some reason the scope isn't working, it is showing every record, wheather it's true or false.. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I can only guess that actually. You could try the `menu :parent => 'Topic'` statement so it'll be a sub menu. That's the only Idea I have in mind. And for the scope, could you provide the model code?